# Has anyone any experience on implementing the R Package XGBoost within the Azure ML Studio environment?

Tags: cortana-intelligence, xgboost, azure-machine-learning-service

I was hoping that someone would have tried to or had success in implementing it and would have knowledge of any pitfalls in using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to zip & load the package windows binaries in dataset & import it to the R environment.

You can follow the instructions over [here](https://gallery.azure.ai/Experiment/Using-XGBoost-to-build-Graduation-Admit-Model-1). I couldn't import it for the latest version, so I simply downloaded the xgboost version from this experiment & loaded it to my saved datasets

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/benjguin/how-to-upload-an-r-package-to-azure-machine-learning) is for any generic packages which are not preloaded in the environment

The following is a [list of experiments](https://web.archive.org/web/20161020215633/https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/machine-learning-r-csharp-web-service-examples/) to publish R models as a web service

Hope this helps!

Edit: You can also simply change the R version to Microsoft Open R (current version 3.2.2) and you can import xgboost as any common library

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Experiment/How-to-Use-XGBoost-in-Azure-ML-1?share=1) you can find an example. It shows for example that you would need to import external libraries individually for both training and scoring.